# Notice: Trying to get property 'sys_id' of non-object

Tags: php, symfony

I have problem in my symfony project that i don't understand. I try to add relations to a fonction, and when i synchronize my app i have this error: "Notice: Trying to get property 'sys_id' of non-object".
I have set my $sys_id in my ResultSnowDto like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Dto\Snow\Orga\Relation;

use App\Dto\Snow\Orga\ReferenceLinkSnowDto;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;

class RelationSnowDto
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @SerializedName("sys_id")
     */
    public $sys_id;

    /**
     *
     * @var ReferenceLinkSnowDto
     */
    public $parent;

    /**
     *
     * @var ReferenceLinkSnowDto
     */
    public $type;

    /**
     *
     * @var ReferenceLinkSnowDto
     */
    public $child;

}
```

After i synchronize my relations with this function:

```
 protected function synchronizeRelations()
    {
        $relation_list_raw = $this->snowTableApiClient->request('GET', 'cmdb_rel_ci', [
            'query' => [
                'sysparm_query' => 'type=60bc4e22c0a8010e01f074cbe6bd73c3^ORtype=1a9cb166f1571100a92eb60da2bce5c5^parent.sys_class_name=cmdb_ci_service^ORparent.sys_class_name=cmdb_ci_appl',
                'sysparm_fields' => 'sys_id,parent,type,child',
                'sysparm_limit' => 10
            ]
        ]);
        $this->logger->info('Synchronize relations');

        return $this->serializer->deserialize(
            $relation_list_raw->getContent(),
            RelationResultSnowDto::class,
            'json'
        );
    }
```

And then, i call my synchronizeRelations in other function like that:

```
 //
            // Deal with relationships between business services and technical components
            //
            //
            $servers = [];

            $rels = $this->synchronizeRelations();

            foreach ($rels as $rel) {
                foreach ($outbound_relations as $outbound_relation) {

                    if ($rel->sys_id === $outbound_relation->sys_id) {

                        $servers[] = $this->businessServicesRelations($rel, $rels);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I tryed to dump $rels, it's work, i have an array with the sys_id but when i try to dump $rel after my "if" it return me nothing.
Someone can help me?
Thank you all!

PS: result when i var-dump $rels
[var_dump($rels)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HILDM.png)

result when i var_dump $outbound_relation:
[var_dump($outbound_relation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCoM3.png)

Comment: The error is saying that `$rel` is not an object. Don't dump `$rel` after the `if` (because the condition can never match). Dump it at the start.

Comment: Yes i have done, but i want to know how can i catch the sys_id of $rel

Comment: Well, what is `$rel`? If it's not an object, is it an array?

Comment: yes it's an array

Comment: So... use array access instead of property access.

Comment: ok thank you i'm gonna try

Comment: Sorry it's not an array it's an object

Comment: Can you just add the whole dump of `$rels` into the question?

Comment: yes i update my post

Comment: Then maybe `$outbound_relation` is the problem. You access `sys_id` on that too.

Comment: When i var_dump $outbound_relation it's work before the if but if i do it after the if it's not work

Comment: Just like with the first try, nothing after the if is executed. The condition can never be satisfied. So, what did the dump of `$outbound_relation` show?

Comment: i just update the post, you can see what var_dump($outbound_relation) show

Comment: Well, since both dumps show objects, I don't see how this code could cause this notice. Are you certain about the line that's causing it?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, the line error is the line of the "if". Don't understand what's happen too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem like this:

```
$servers = [];

            $rels = $this->synchronizeRelations();

            foreach ($rels->relations as $rel) {
                foreach ($outbound_relations as $outbound_relation) {
                    if ($rel->parent->value === $outbound_relation->sys_id) {
                        $servers[] = $this->businessServicesRelations($rel, $rels);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you El_Vanja !